# How do you get team points in dominion?

Tags: for-honor

I've been playing For Honor and noticed that the total points for each player on the score board is not the same as the team points in the top right of the screen.

[image: Here is an example]

- Attackers had 699 team points.
  The players had 408, 399, 323, and 88 score each.
  Total Score: 1218
- Defenders had 444 team points.
  The players had 181, 153, 141, and 109 score each.
  Total Score: 584

Since it doesn't seem to be based on player scores, what is it based on?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Team points are based on zones. Where there are five states that zones can be in:

- Unallocated
  This is the state that zones start in, they're not controlled by anyone and don't show up in the team point bars.
- Controlled
  The zone is controlled by a team, but no-one, friendly or enemy, is in it. The zone is placed in the team point bar that controls it with a +1 at the top. Your team also gain a bonus 100 points until the zone is lost.
- Boosted
  The zone is controlled by a team, with more than one friendly player in the zone. The zone shows up in the team point bar, but with a +2 at the top.

  [When boosting a zone you get a popup saying](https://i.stack.imgur.com/avGWX.png):

  > ### BOOSTED
  >
  > DEFEND to KEEP your 100 pts and 2 pts/sec
- Contested
  The zone has one or more of both an enemy and friendly player in it. The zone shows up in the controlled teams point bar switching between; grey and black. No points are gained from it.
- Being captured
  The zone is either; controlled by a team, or unallocated, but one or more enemy players are in the zone. If the zone is controlled, it shows up in the controlled teams point bar switching between; the capturing teams colour, and black. No points are gained from it.

And so the only time you get team points are when a zone is either being; controlled, or boosted. And when you have a zone in your team point bar you gain a bonus 100 points.

To note, zones that have week AI warriors fighting, seem to not be able to be; boosted, or contested.

---

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k7ohc.png), for example, is what the team point bar looks like when the Defenders are; contesting Zone A, controlling Zone B, and boosting Zone C.